# Counting unique values in column with filtered data

Tags: google-sheets, count, filtering, unique

Take for example this spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoSVxswDPXtwdE5HcGZ4Y0lsMlZtZmFHRjZTcnpGS0E&usp=sharing

Data is like this:

```
Date              Week          Project
3-jan-2013         1-2013       Project 1
4-jan-2013         1-2013       Project 1
5-jan-2013         1-2013       Project 1
6-jan-2013         1-2013       Project 1
18-abr-2013       16-2013       Project 2
19-abr-2013       16-2013       Project 2
22-abr-2013       17-2013       Project 2
24-abr-2013       17-2013       Project 2
25-abr-2013       17-2013       Project 2
26-abr-2013       17-2013       Project 2
29-abr-2013       18-2013       Project 2
30-abr-2013       18-2013       Project 2
1-mai-2013        18-2013       Project 2
3-mai-2013        18-2013       Project 2
4-mai-2013        18-2013       Project 2
6-mai-2013        19-2013       Project 2
7-mai-2013        19-2013       Project 2
8-mai-2013        19-2013       Project 2
9-mai-2013        19-2013       Project 2
10-mai-2013       19-2013       Project 2
7-jan-2013         2-2013       Project 1
8-jan-2013         2-2013       Project 1
16-mai-2012       20-2012       Project 1
17-mai-2012       20-2012       Project 1
```

I thought [SUBTOTAL](https://drive.googleblog.com/2011/09/tips-tricks-using-new-subtotal-function.html) could handle this but it doesn't work for unique values out of the box...

I have a filter in column `Project` where `Project 2` is selected. In cell `C2` I'd like it to report `4` as a result of `=COUNTUNIQUE(C4:C)`. It's reporting `7`, that is, it's considering all the values in column `C` ignoring the filter. If I select `Project 1` in the filter, it should report `3` and finally if all projects are selected it should then report `7`.

For `Project 2` there are `4` unique week values:

```
16-2013
17-2013
18-2013
19-2013
```

For `Project 1` there are `3` unique week values:

```
 1-2013
 2-2013
20-2012
```

How can I achieve `COUNTUNIQUE` with filtered data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way of achieving this without a helper column (which you can hide if you like).

So for example, in E4:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(D4:D);MMULT((ROW(D4:D)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(D4:D)))*(D4:D=TRANSPOSE(D4:D))*(C4:C=TRANSPOSE(C4:C));SIGN(ROW(D4:D)))=0;IFERROR(1/0)))`

Then in C2 you can invoke:

`=SUBTOTAL(9;E4:E)`

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Worked great! A really neat solution in a somewhat long array formula. :) Thank you very much Adam for the help.

Comment: Hey Adam: what about this different beast? :D https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/Ax4ZpogAtok/kFCmj1Q_zWIJ I tried applying this same technique (with a helper column) but I can't get it to work on all conditions, that is, with all Projects selected and then with only 1 Project selected. :( Of course I could achieve that with a Pivot Table but I'd like to have that unique count updated by the filter in the data table itself.

Comment: Apologies for missing this Leniel, will answer on the GPF thread.

Comment: Adam... you nailed it again. Just amazing... I would never thought about doing that!